# Is the integral operator with continuous kernel from $H^{-\frac 1 2}(\partial\Omega)$ to $H^{\frac 1 2}(\partial\Omega)$ a compact operator?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, compact-operators, integral-operators

For a bounded domain $\Omega$ with $C^1$ boundary, define a integral operator $A$ with a continuous kernel $k$ satisfies
$$
A f (x) = \int_{\partial\Omega} k(x,y)f(y)~{\rm d}y \quad {\rm for }~x\in\partial\Omega.
$$
Here $k(x,y)$ is continuous on $\partial\Omega \times \partial\Omega$.

I know $A:L^2(\partial\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\partial\Omega)$ is compact. Then is $A:H^{-\frac 1 2}(\partial\Omega) \rightarrow H^{\frac 1 2}(\partial\Omega)$ still compact?

Comment: It is not even continuous there ... the range could contain functions that are just continuous

Comment: You mean the operator $A$​ is not continuous or bounded?
$$
 \lVert Af\rVert_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}^2 = \int_{\partial\Omega} \left| \int_{\partial\Omega} k(x,y)f(y)~{\rm d}y\right|^2~{\rm d}x \leq C \int_{\partial\Omega} \left| \int_{\partial\Omega} f(y)~{\rm d}y\right|^2~{\rm d}x \leq C \lVert f\rVert_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}^2,
$$
You mean the inequality above does not hold if $L^2$ are replaced by $H^{-\frac 1 2},~H^{\frac 1 2}$. Acutally, I have no idea about the estimate of $H^{-\frac1 2}$, can you recommend some reference ?

Comment: @LL3.14
And I know $H^{\frac 1 2}$ is a subspace of $L^2$, how about $H^{-\frac 1 2}$? Is it a subpace of $L^2$ or Does it contains L^2?